# Using the Fibocom L830-EB in ArchLinux on a ThinkPad T480s

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, thinkpad, mobile

I want to have mobile broadband on my T480s. First I ordered the L850-GL which didn't work because it uses the PCI interface. [As you can see in this forum.](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Linux-support-for-WWAN-LTE-L850-GL-on-T580-T480/td-p/4067969) People in the same thread claim to have a working L830-EB on their devices and in [this (german) forum](https://thinkpad-forum.de/threads/212770-T480s-mit-Linux) someone has managed to use the same module with Kubuntu.

I could successfully use the module in a Windows 10 VM. This and the fact that I could not find a "Lenovo Activation App" for my system lets me assume that the activation is successful or not necessary.

I tried following [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ThinkPad_mobile_internet#Procedure) but the result is:

```
$ sudo ./qmi_setup.sh start
error: couldn't open the QmiDevice: Operation timed out: device is closed
your wwan device may be RFKilled?
```

The censored output of `mmcli` is:

```
$ mmcli -m 0
  --------------------------------
  General  |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |            device id: 8f2545cc6e144c03ae986f13ea3a5ed42b03ecfd
  --------------------------------
  Hardware |         manufacturer: FIBOCOM
           |                model: L830-EB-00
           |             revision: 18300.1002.00.01.01.11
           |         h/w revision: L830-EB-02 v1.0.1
           |            supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |              current: gsm-umts, lte
           |         equipment id: XXXXXXXXX
  --------------------------------
  System   |               device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6
           |              drivers: cdc_acm, cdc_mbim
           |               plugin: Fibocom
           |         primary port: cdc-wdm0
           |                ports: cdc-wdm0 (mbim), ttyACM0 (at), wwp0s20f0u6 (net)
  --------------------------------
  Numbers  |                  own: XXXXXXXX
  --------------------------------
  Status   |       unlock retries: sim-pin (3)
           |                state: registered
           |          power state: on
           |          access tech: lte
           |       signal quality: 12% (recent)
  --------------------------------
  Modes    |            supported: allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: none
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                       allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |              current: allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
  --------------------------------
  Bands    |            supported: utran-1, utran-5, utran-8, eutran-1, eutran-3, eutran-5, 
           |                       eutran-7, eutran-8, eutran-20, eutran-28
           |              current: utran-1, utran-5, utran-8, eutran-1, eutran-3, eutran-5, 
           |                       eutran-7, eutran-8, eutran-20, eutran-28
  --------------------------------
  IP       |            supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  --------------------------------
  3GPP     |                 imei: XXXXXX
           |        enabled locks: sim
           |          operator id: 26202
           |        operator name: Vodafone.de
           |         registration: home
  --------------------------------
  3GPP EPS | ue mode of operation: csps-2
  --------------------------------
  SIM      |            dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
```

When the desktop environment starts I get asked for the SIM pin. When I want to choose a Network in NetworkManager the only option is to "Add a new connection". When I choose this option the NetworkManager window closes.

[image: NetworkManager window]

I don't know what else to check now. Can you please give me some pointers?

**Update:**

Checking the status of ModemManager reveals that the device is not supported. I wonder how the other people managed to connect...

```
Apr 09 18:31:55 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3': not supported by any plugin
Apr 09 18:31:55 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:3d:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Apr 09 18:31:55 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6': not supported by any plugin
Apr 09 18:31:55 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: opening device...
Apr 09 18:31:55 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Read max control message size from descriptors file: 512
Apr 09 18:31:55 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] channel destroyed
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6] creating modem with plugin 'Fibocom' and '3' ports
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Modem for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6' successfully created
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: opening device...
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Read max control message size from descriptors file: 512
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Opening device with flags 'version-info, proxy, mbim, expect-indications'...
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] loaded driver of cdc-wdm port: cdc_mbim
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] creating MBIM device...
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] MBIM device created
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] opening MBIM device...
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: opening device...
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Read max control message size from descriptors file: 512
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] MBIM device open
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Checking version info (15 retries)...
Apr 09 18:31:56 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] sending message as MBIM...
Apr 09 18:31:57 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  [cdc-wdm0] MBIM device is not QMI capable
Apr 09 18:31:57 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] MBIM device wasn't explicitly closed
Apr 09 18:31:57 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: [/dev/cdc-wdm0] channel destroyed
Apr 09 18:31:57 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <warn>  Unexpected band value: 1-2
Apr 09 18:31:58 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Modem: state changed (unknown -> locked)
Apr 09 18:31:58 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <warn>  couldn't load Operator identifier: 'PinRequired'
Apr 09 18:31:58 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <warn>  couldn't load Operator name: 'PinRequired'
Apr 09 18:32:10 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: state changed (locked -> initializing)
Apr 09 18:32:21 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <warn>  couldn't load initial EPS bearer settings: 'Transaction timed out'
Apr 09 18:32:21 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <warn>  couldn't load SUPL server: 'Operation not supported'
Apr 09 18:32:21 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: state changed (initializing -> disabled)
Apr 09 18:32:21 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: state changed (disabled -> enabling)
Apr 09 18:32:31 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: state changed (enabling -> enabled)
Apr 09 18:32:31 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: 3GPP Registration state changed (unknown -> registering)
Apr 09 18:32:31 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: 3GPP Registration state changed (registering -> home)
Apr 09 18:32:31 tinkerpad ModemManager[1114]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/1: state changed (enabled -> registered)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [the mentioned forum](https://thinkpad-forum.de/threads/212770-T480s-mit-Linux):

> Die Lösung war, dass ich vergaß, dass ich im Network-Manager manuell das Profil anlegen muss. Da ja nicht, wie beim WLAN, abgescannt wird. War ein einfacher...tollpatschiger, unüberlegter aber mein Fehler. Es funktioniert jetzt.

Translation:

> The solution was to manually create a profile in Network-Manager. Because, in contrast to WLAN, it is not scanned. Was a simple...foolish, thoughtless but my mistake. Now it works.

I can only agree. But I still think NetworkManager should not "crash" when adding a connection through the wrong dialog.